# PHP pull and display values from API url

Tags: php, json, curl

If I use the following:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.website.com/api/v1/members/102210');
echo $homepage;
```

The data is displayed as follows:

```
{"user":{"profile":{"Id":{"Label":"User Id","Value":102210},"User":{"Label":"User Name","Value":"tom"}
```

I tried the following that I discovered on here in another post but the page remains blank other than User:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.website.com/api/v1/members/102210",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


$response = json_decode($response, true); //because of true, it's in an array
echo 'User: '. $response['User']['User Name'];
```

Comment: What is the issue ? Can u please format Json and paste it buddy

Comment: can you print the `$response` var please ? `print_r($response);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the JSON data. There is no `User` key in the root of the json object and there is no `User Name` key inside of that either. When you [visualize the JSON](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=8e0bb1c6bdd4f88645532156b3bdc8d2), this is what it looks like:

[image: json]

What you seem to be looking for is:

```
echo 'User: ' . $response['user']['profile']['User']['Value'];
```

I'm not sure why you'd switch to cURL if the file_get_content method works for you. You should be able to simply do this:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.website.com/api/v1/members/102210');
$response = json_decode($homepage, true);

echo 'User: ' . $response['user']['profile']['User']['Value'];
```

Comment: what tool are you using to create the tree diagram? Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter jsoneditoronline.org, added link to the example in the answer.

Comment: @Oldskool it only displays blank page

Comment: @William I adjusted the answer a little to show a more complete example. That should show the user and username. If not, your curl request probably throws an error (try adding `var_dump($err)` to the end of the script to see).

Comment: @William On second thought, it looks like file_get_contents works well for you, so why switch to cURL at all? Added an alternative example.

Comment: @Oldskool I added it to the end it said string(0) ""

Comment: if I use file get it displays everything but I don't need it to echo everything

Comment: @Oldskool if you look at the top code $homepage file get at the start of my post it echos everything and I just want to echo a few.. how can I do that with file gets?

Comment: @William You don't need to echo everything, but you'll have to get the complete response ($homepage) in order to be able to actually parse the JSON.

Comment: thank you so much @Oldskool the reason I did was someone posted never use file_gets on a post here

Comment: @Oldskool just got one more question for you see at the end on the link where user number is? can I add this $username = ['user']; then at the end of the link /api/v1/members/$username');